# How to format double to look like an integer in my programme? The chess board rice legend

Tags: java, exponential

If I run my programme it gives me double numbers, but in the end those numbers aren't like integers anymore because there is a point in them. Can you tell me how to format it or handle this? Thanks

```
package writingtofile;

import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class WritingToFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int counter = 1;

        FileWriter out = null;
        try{
        out = new FileWriter("out.txt");
        for(double number : FibanocciNumbers())
        {
            out.write("Spot:");
            out.write(counter + " ");
            out.write(String.valueOf(number) + "\r\n");
            counter++;
        }
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
        System.out.println("Error!");
        }
        finally
        {
        out.close();
        }
    }
    public static double[] FibanocciNumbers()
    {
        double[] fibNumbers = new double[64];
        fibNumbers[0] = 1;
        fibNumbers[1] = 2;
        double lastNumber;
        for(int i = 2; i < 64; i++)
        {
        lastNumber = fibNumbers[i-1];
        fibNumbers[i] = lastNumber * 2;
        }
        return fibNumbers;
```

---

```
Spot:1 1.0
Spot:2 2.0
Spot:3 4.0
Spot:4 8.0
Spot:5 16.0
Spot:6 32.0
Spot:7 64.0
Spot:8 128.0
Spot:9 256.0
Spot:10 512.0
Spot:11 1024.0
Spot:12 2048.0
Spot:13 4096.0
Spot:14 8192.0
Spot:15 16384.0
Spot:16 32768.0
Spot:17 65536.0
Spot:18 131072.0
Spot:19 262144.0
Spot:20 524288.0
Spot:21 1048576.0
Spot:22 2097152.0
Spot:23 4194304.0
Spot:24 8388608.0
Spot:25 1.6777216E7
Spot:26 3.3554432E7
Spot:27 6.7108864E7
Spot:28 1.34217728E8
Spot:29 2.68435456E8
Spot:30 5.36870912E8
Spot:31 1.073741824E9
Spot:32 2.147483648E9
Spot:33 4.294967296E9
Spot:34 8.589934592E9
Spot:35 1.7179869184E10
Spot:36 3.4359738368E10
Spot:37 6.8719476736E10
Spot:38 1.37438953472E11
Spot:39 2.74877906944E11
Spot:40 5.49755813888E11
Spot:41 1.099511627776E12
Spot:42 2.199023255552E12
Spot:43 4.398046511104E12
Spot:44 8.796093022208E12
Spot:45 1.7592186044416E13
Spot:46 3.5184372088832E13
Spot:47 7.0368744177664E13
Spot:48 1.40737488355328E14
Spot:49 2.81474976710656E14
Spot:50 5.62949953421312E14
Spot:51 1.125899906842624E15
Spot:52 2.251799813685248E15
Spot:53 4.503599627370496E15
Spot:54 9.007199254740992E15
Spot:55 1.8014398509481984E16
Spot:56 3.6028797018963968E16
Spot:57 7.2057594037927936E16
Spot:58 1.44115188075855872E17
Spot:59 2.8823037615171174E17
Spot:60 5.7646075230342349E17
Spot:61 1.15292150460684698E18
Spot:62 2.305843009213694E18
Spot:63 4.6116860184273879E18
```

### Spot:64 9.223372036854776E18

So I don't wnat those numbers with points in it, because I think it changes the way you should understand this. How to get them away or handle them? Tanks

Comment: you should have a look at `NumberFormat` class

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "those numbers aren't like integers anymore because there is a point in them". Do you want to cast the doubles to integers?

Comment: Probably want to cast to a long to handle up to 64 Fib numbers; btw those aren't fib numbers, just powers of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code using BigInteger. Its what you want, no decimal!!
also, double is not an integer, its like float but with capability to to hold large fractional numbers. btw **you have named it FibanocciNumbers but those are not fibonnaci numbers**

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {

        int counter = 1;

        FileWriter out = null;
        try{
        out = new FileWriter("out.txt");
        for(BigInteger number : FibanocciNumbers())
        {
            out.write("Spot:");
            out.write(counter + " ");
            out.write(String.valueOf(number) + "\r\n");
            System.out.println(number);
            counter++;
        }
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
        System.out.println("Error!");
        }
        finally
        {
        out.close();
        }
    }

    public static BigInteger[] FibanocciNumbers()
    {
        BigInteger[] fibNumbers = new BigInteger[64];
        fibNumbers[0] = new BigInteger("1");
        fibNumbers[1] = new BigInteger("2");
        BigInteger lastNumber;
        for(int i = 2; i < 64; i++)
        {
            lastNumber = fibNumbers[i-1];
            fibNumbers[i] = lastNumber.multiply( new BigInteger("2") );
        }
        return fibNumbers;
    }
}
```

last line of Output:
    **Spot:64 9223372036854775808**

Comment: Yea I know I that those aren't Fibanocci Numbers, but I just wanted to change something quickly. But thanks alot! Good work, because I didn't know how to handle BigInteger :)